# Process launch failed: launch or suspend in progress

Tags: ios, deployment, xcode5

While running any project on my mac using xocde 5.1 I am getting error `Process launch failed: launch or suspend in progress` . I know there are same questions asked on stack but none of the answer resolved my issue. Can anybody take me out of this?

[image: Error]

Comment: One more thing to add the error message is not specific. Sometimes it "Timed out" sometime it is "launch or suspend in progress".'

Comment: This may be issue of X-code ,try to quite Xcode and relaunch app.

Answer (score 3):

You try rebooting the device by holding the power and home buttons

Comment: Totally worked! My iPod Touch hanged after getting process launch failure.